# Variables aren't returning from switch statement

Tags: php, drupal-7, switch-statement

I am working in Drupal and trying to return a new URL in the lower function. The trouble I am having is that the `$path` variable I am returning doesn't persist the `$vocab` and `$site` variable.

Also, for non-Drupal users, the `ccw_taxonomy_baseurl_filter_url_inbound_alter()` function is automatically called so that is not the problem. I am hoping this is a syntax issue or something inside the switch because I have spent a lot of time debugging this.

```
function __extractURLName($myurl){
  $domain = parse_url($myurl , PHP_URL_HOST);
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $list)) {
    return substr($list['domain'], 0,strpos($list['domain'], "."));
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_url_inbound_alter().
 */
function ccw_taxonomy_baseurl_filter_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {

  if($path =='taxonomy/term/%'){
    $path = '';
    $url = __extractURLName(url(NULL, array('absolute' => TRUE)));
    $site = 0;
    $vocab = arg(2);

    switch ($url) {
      case 'bmagazine':
        $site = 5;
        $vocab = arg(2);
        break;
      case 'emagazine':
        if (arg(0) == 'high') {
          $site = 4;
          $vocab = arg(3);
          break;
        } else {
          $site = 3;
          $vocab = arg(3);
          break;
        }
      case 'smagazine':
        $site = 2;
        $vocab = arg(2);
        break;
      case 'fmagazine':
        $site = 1;
        $vocab = arg(2);
        break;
      default:
        $site = 1;
        break;
    }
    $path = 'taxonomy/term/'.$vocab.'/'.$site;
  }
  dpm($path); // debugging tool
  return $path;
}
```

By the way, `arg()` is a drupal function as well that grabs a URL path variable.

Comment: arg(); is a drupal function as well that grabs a url path variable

Comment: Are you sure about the content of `$url` variable before the `switch` block? Try to debug it to check its value.

Comment: $url resolves correctly. Thanks Gustavo for the question.

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting for you to check if the value of `$url` matches one of the cases from your `switch` block. Also, what is the output from that call to `dpm()`?

Comment: @GustavoStraube I was able to figure out the problem. The if condition that checks the path, instead of 'taxonomy/term/%', with % being a placeholder for a contextual filter, I changed it to 'taxonomy/term/'.arg(2) which matches the path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check comments for answer under the question for more detail, but I solved the problem by changed the path